# Jquery Ajax not working with Zend Framework- Json returns parsererror

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework

I'm new to zend framework. Here I trying get an array from controller to jquery ajax function in view. But when 'dataType' changed to 'json' its call error.

How could I send an array from controller to jquery and How to receive it. Please Help

---

**Controller**

---

```
public function init()
{
 $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
        $ajaxContext->addActionContext('ajax', 'json')
                    ->initContext();

 }
 public function ajaxAction(){

    // DO THE OTHER STUFF AND LOGIC HERE

    $results = array(
        'return1' => 'value1',
        'return2' => 'value2'
    );

    echo $this->_helper->sendJson($results);
}
```

---

**View**

---

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#selectOptions").change(function(){

        var param1 = 'first';  //or get value from some DOM element
        var param2 = 'second'; //or get value from some DOM element

        $.ajax ({
            url: 'index/ajax',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            async : false,
            data: {param1: param1, param2:param2 },
            success: function(json){
                console.log(json);

            },
            error : function(xhr, status){
                console.log(status);
            },
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in your controller

```
$this->_helper->sendJson($results);
```

or

```
$this->_helper->json($results);
```

but without the echo

Comment: I already tried that one. But its not working. Ajax still calling error function. but 'dataType' html gets 'success'. Any other .phtml (ajax.ajax.phtml) is required for ajax action??

Comment: I figured out error. url: '/index/ajax'. Anyway thanks for your valuable time.